# azure bot unable to find client secret

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am in the proccess of registering an azure bot on azure in order to create a custom app with yo teams following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-task-modules/7-exercise-use-task-modules-bots but when I come to generate the client secret under certificates & secrets, the certificates and secrets option is not available as described in the tutorial. Does the interface of the azure has been changed or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of what you are seeing

Answer (score 2):

While creating the Azure bot resource if you have followed the same as exercise and selected the option "*Create new Microsoft App ID*" then what you need to do is copy the App Id from the configuration page.

[image]

Once copied go to home of Azure portal and navigate or search App registrations
[image]

Go inside and search your app by pasting Id in
[image]
Once you find it you should be able to see the "*Certificates & secrets*" and you can proceed with the exercise.

Comment: I followed your instructions but still I am not able to register it. I copy my bots ID then go to app registrations and when I search with the application ID finds nothing

Comment: You can also try by switching All application and owned application or Maybe navigate to Azure Active Directory and check once in Enterprise application

Comment: In enterprise applications I can find it but the menu is diferrent, it does not show certifications and secrets tab. Do you know why I can find it in enterprise tab but not under my app?

Comment: You should be able to see it in All application and owned application under the right tenant. Could you please confirm once more to be sure that you looked in right directory and tried switching between these two options.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. When I was creating the azure bot under type of app option I selected user-assigned managed identity instead I should choose single tenant.

Comment: In App registration section you will get the "Certificates & secrets". Could you please check it once or share the screenshot what you get?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSTs3.png

Comment: @christos.goulas- Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?